# Can someone help me solve the Question on Differentiabilty

Tags: derivatives

I need help with solution of this question.

[image]

Which of them is differentiable at x=0.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows Are you a Darren Shan fan?

Comment: I don't know who that is.

Comment: **Hint.** What is the behavior of $|x|$ near $x = 0$?  We know that's not differentiable at $x = 0$, so if any of these choices is differentiable, that behavior must be cancelled out by the other part of the expression.  So what is the behavior of $e^{|x|}$ near $x = 0$?  The behavior of $e^{-|x|}$?

Answer (score 0):

|x| is not differentiable at x=0. So none of the options qualify.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Precisely.But the answer key says it's c.And remember this is from a sample questions by an IIT.That's the reason why I am perplexed.

Comment: @PrasadKulkarni: Note that if you had $(|x|+2)-|x|$, that would be differentiable, even though neither $|x|+2$ nor $|x|$ is itself differentiable.  That's the sort of thing you should be looking for in these choices.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Tung.But can you please elaborate a bit more on how the example you provided is differentiable.

Comment: @PrasadKulkarni: Well, symbolically, it's clear that $(|x|+2)-|x| = |x|+2-|x| = 2$ which is obviously differentiable (and has constant derivative equal to zero).  But more important is that the two parts have the same kind of discontinuity.  Both $|x|+2$ and $|x|$ have exactly one point at which the derivative does not exist: at $x = 0$.  Further, both derivatives in some sense do the same thing at that point, they jump up by $2$ (from $-1$ to $1$) in both cases.  Therefore, when you subtract one from the other, you in a sense cancel out the discontinuities.  The same thing happens in (c).

Comment: Incidentally, this answer is in error; it should not be upvoted.  Even if the conclusion were correct, the reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Thank you Brian! It helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use Taylor's series to expand exponential function to find that all options except  'c', will cancel out other non differentiable term.

Comment: Tried it.Agreed that the |x| gets cancelled out in c.But what about the higher order terms?Can you please elaborate.Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: higher order terms of $|x|$, are differerntiable at 0.in fact $|x|$ raised to any power greater than 1 is differentiable at 0. apply the definition of differentitation to see it yourself.